# OpenCv integer array conversion

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv, pixel

I have an array of ints (an image of dimensions numangle*numrho actually, in a variable called accum) that I would like to convert into an opencv Mat structure for display, and am having a little trouble.  I create an OutputArray and fill its data with the values from the integer array ; since the OutputArray data is uchars apparently (even though I declared CV_32SC1 which is for 32bit signed integer 1 channel images) I fill it in byte by byte as follows:

```
int s = sizeof(accum[0]);  
_acc.create(numangle+2,numrho+2,CV_32SC1);  
Mat accumulator = _acc.getMat();  
for(int r = 0; r < numrho; r++ )
            for(int n = 0; n < numangle; n++ )
            {
                int base = r * (numangle)+n;
                accumulator.data[base*s+3] = accum[base] & 0xFF; 
                accumulator.data[base*s+2] = (accum[base]>>8) & 0xFF;
                accumulator.data[base*s+1] = (accum[base]>>16) & 0xFF; 
                accumulator.data[base*s+0] = (accum[base]>>24) & 0xFF;  
          //    accumulator.at(int)(r,n)=accum[base];
             }
```

However I seem to wind up with a 1-bit image albeit of the correct dimensions. I'm a little rusty on my pointer arithmetic, maybe I don't need the base*s .  Also iiuc if I were to use accumulator.at(x,y) it would be significantly slower?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
int index=0;
for(int r = 0; r < numrho; r++ )
{
    int* row=reinterpret_cast<int*>(accumulator.ptr(r));
    for(int n = 0; n < numangle; n++ )
      row[n]=accum[index++];
}
```

Alternatively, if the array is a simple buffer, you can attach it to an image (without losing ownership of the buffer), by doing:

```
Mat image(numrho,numangle,CV_32SC1,accum);
```

This approach doesn't copy the data, which is sometimes what you want.

Comment: thanks that looks like a good way. I've tried it a cpl times but so far run into memory errors (exit code 139 when I call this from python which is where I am usually working these days); this couldnt be due to getting the width instead of height I blv.  The error hits a short way in, at n,r=32,202  of a 180,3000 array.  The original memory is allocated thru         `memset( accum, 0, sizeof(accum[0]) * (numangle+2) * (numrho+2) );`

Comment: memset doesn't allocate memory.

Comment: ok you are correct sire    `AutoBuffer<int> _accum((numangle+2) * (numrho+2));
    int *accum = _accum;` is the allocation, which doesn't help me understand why the code as is still crashes.  I'm not familiar with reinterpret_cast so I'm now trying `accumulator.at(int)(r,n)=accum[base]` , here goes another 30-minute compile and test cycle.

Comment: ok the accumulator.at   version works.  For my own curiosity and possibly faster code I will retry the indexed version and see how it goes now that I have gdb working with opencv.